# How to uninstall netbeans if uninstall.sh missing

Tags: netbeans

I can't find  `uninstall.sh` in my netbeans folder. Please help. I want it to be removed. Thanks.

Output commandline

```
seng@wseng:~$ sudo apt remove netbeans
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'netbeans' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 416 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Will you describe how you installed Netbeans?

Comment: what is the output of `dpkg -l | grep netbeans` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From the commandline run:**

```
$ sudo apt remove netbeans
```

**Alternatively (using the GUI):**

Run `Ubuntu Software`.  Type in `Netbeans` in the search fiend.  Click `Remove`.

Comment: I tried the commandline and it said done. But the netbeans still can be opened.

Comment: What is the results of this command `type netbeans`?

Comment: I have edited my post.